# plot daily and weekly variation date data in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to plot blood pressure data to make a plot where I can see within day (hour to hour), day to day within week. Here is prototype plot I am expecting.

[image]

I need to automate the ploting and the app that produce data will have the following format:

```
    mydHeart <- data.frame (datetime = paste("12/", rep(1:10, each=4), "/14 ", 
  rep(c("14:14:00", "12:15:00", "18:15:14", "22:15:14"), 4), " PM", sep=""), 
systolic = round(rnorm(40, 120, 5),0), distolic= round(rnorm(40, 80, 3),0))

                   datetime systolic distolic
    1   12/1/14 14:14:00 PM      126       76
    2   12/1/14 12:15:00 PM      126       79
    3   12/1/14 18:15:14 PM      122       79
    4   12/1/14 22:15:14 PM      130       84
    5   12/2/14 14:14:00 PM      122       80
    6   12/2/14 12:15:00 PM      120       79
    7   12/2/14 18:15:14 PM      119       82
    8   12/2/14 22:15:14 PM      126       80
    9   12/3/14 14:14:00 PM      123       81
    10  12/3/14 12:15:00 PM      122       84
    11  12/3/14 18:15:14 PM      126       79
    12  12/3/14 22:15:14 PM      122       78
    13  12/4/14 14:14:00 PM      128       74
    14  12/4/14 12:15:00 PM      114       81
    15  12/4/14 18:15:14 PM      122       84
    16  12/4/14 22:15:14 PM      114       81
    17  12/5/14 14:14:00 PM      126       79
    18  12/5/14 12:15:00 PM      121       77
    19  12/5/14 18:15:14 PM      125       86
    20  12/5/14 22:15:14 PM      128       79
    21  12/6/14 14:14:00 PM      114       86
    22  12/6/14 12:15:00 PM      129       81
    23  12/6/14 18:15:14 PM      117       80
    24  12/6/14 22:15:14 PM      126       82
    25  12/7/14 14:14:00 PM      118       88
    26  12/7/14 12:15:00 PM      114       81
    27  12/7/14 18:15:14 PM      124       79
    28  12/7/14 22:15:14 PM      120       76
    29  12/8/14 14:14:00 PM      119       79
    30  12/8/14 12:15:00 PM      114       79
    31  12/8/14 18:15:14 PM      117       85
    32  12/8/14 22:15:14 PM      117       78
    33  12/9/14 14:14:00 PM      120       78
    34  12/9/14 12:15:00 PM      126       83
    35  12/9/14 18:15:14 PM      121       79
    36  12/9/14 22:15:14 PM      119       78
    37 12/10/14 14:14:00 PM      118       79
    38 12/10/14 12:15:00 PM      128       78
    39 12/10/14 18:15:14 PM      133       81
    40 12/10/14 22:15:14 PM      116       81
```

I am trying the base date conversion facilties, but the following code produce funny plot.

```
plot(as.Date(mydHeart[,1]), mydHeart[,2], type = "l")
```

I tried following but gives an error, I am not sure how I can input the above date style in R.

```
    plot(as.Date(mydHeart[,1], '%m-%d-%y'), mydHeart[,2], type = "l")

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I am not sure how names of days are recognized and how I can put the grid lines where they need to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this:

```
mydHeart$datetime <- as.character(mydHeart$datetime)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
##
mydHeart$datetime <- lubridate::mdy_hms(
  sub("(\\s[A-Z]+)","",mydHeart$datetime))
##
> str(mydHeart)
'data.frame':   40 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2014-12-01 14:14:00" ...
 $ systolic: num  120 121 114 122 113 114 120 117 116 126 ...
 $ distolic: num  80 76 83 81 84 79 80 81 83 77 ...
```

The above will get your `datetime` column formatted correctly; from here I would `melt` your data and create a plot with `ggplot2` rather than using R's base graphics, but you may prefer base plots.

```
mData <- melt(
  mydHeart,
  id.vars="datetime",
  variable.name="bp_type",
  value.name="blood_pressure")
##
ggplot(
  mData,
  aes(x=datetime,y=blood_pressure,
      color=bp_type))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(
  labels=date_format("%a %m/%d"))
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Taking @eipi10's suggestions, with a couple of slight modifications:

```
ggplot(
  mData,
  aes(x=datetime,y=blood_pressure,
      color=bp_type))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_datetime(
    breaks="1 day", 
    minor_breaks="6 hours") + 
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim=c(mdy_hms("11/30/14 12:00:00"),
           mdy_hms("12/10/14 00:00:00")))+
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(
      colour="grey30", linetype="11"),
    panel.grid.major.x=element_line(
      colour="black"))+
  geom_line(size=1.1)
```

[image]

I set the minor gridline interval to 6 hours, otherwise the figure gets pretty congested with vertical lines, but you can certainly change this to your liking.

Comment: You can also add `scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 day")` to get the major gridlines 1 day apart, and `theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_line(colour="black"))` to get black vertical lines marking the day boundaries.

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you, I'll add your suggestions to my answer.

Comment: thanks , How about minor gridlines - at hour interval ?

Comment: `scale_x_datetime(limits=c(mdy_hms("12/1/14 00:00:00"),mdy_hms("12/9/14 00:00:00")),
                   breaks="1 day", minor_breaks="1 hour")` and `theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_line(colour="grey30", linetype="11"))`

Comment: Notice that the major and minor breaks are not aligned. I would have thought that specifying the left x-limit to start at midnight would have resulted in both major and minor gridlines being aligned at 24-hour and 6-hour intervals starting at midnight, but at least one of them is not aligned at midnight and I can't tell from the graph if either are aligned at midnight.

Comment: Moving the x-limits to `coord_cartesian()` seems to fix it, but I'm not sure why that works but the original version doesn't. Here's the code: `scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 day", minor_breaks="6 hours") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(mdy_hms("11/30/14 12:00:00"),mdy_hms("12/10/14 00:00:00")))`

Comment: @eipi10 Nicely done, thanks again for the suggestions.